# Assign if condition on specific condition matched - c#

Tags: c#

A very basic question on below logic.

If the term starts with double quotes i dont want to do anything. just want to pass it to the next line. But the line `term = term` throws error.

Not sure how to handle it.

```cs
if (term.StartsWith("$"))
{
    // Don't modify the search term
    term = term.Substring(1, term.Length - 1);
    originalTerm = string.Copy(term);
}
else
{
    if (term.StartsWith("\""))
    {
        term = term;
    }
    else
    {
        // Escape special characters
        term = LuceneReservedCharacterPattern.Replace(term, @"\$0"); 
        // Then modify the term to improve phrase match:
        //      lyme disease OR "lyme disease"^2
        term = string.Concat("(", term, ") OR \"", term, "\"^2");
    }
    
    if (collections != null && !collections.Any(c => c.Equals("all", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    {
        // check for multiple collections collections: (all OR this OR that OR him OR her) etc
        term = string.Concat("(", term, ") AND collections:(", string.Join(" OR ", collections), ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use a ; on its own. An empty statement.  You could also reverse your logic, if(!term.Starts.... Then you don't need the else.

Comment: If `term = term;` causes error, all other `term` assignment should also throw. What is the exception?

Comment: As a side note, saying "throws an error" is about as helpful as going to a doctor saying "me bad". What error it is is as important — if not more important — as the fact that an error occurred.

Comment: `term = term` is perfectly valid C#, at least if `term` is a string or any value type (and more likely anything at all other than a property getter that throws). Not sure why would that cause any problems. Would work even if `term` was `null` (see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8SMkIn )

Comment: `term = term` reports [warning CS1717](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1717). The only reason this would error if warnings have been upgraded to errors.

Comment: @StuartLC and that'd still not "throw" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the condition and remove the `else`..? That way, if the condition is `true`, nothing will happen at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do in this situation is to invert your if statement as suggested by Angius. This will completely remove the need for your problematic line of code (I suspect the issue with it is that your are setting a variable to itself).

The following should work:

```
if (term.StartsWith("$"))
        {
            // Don't modify the search term
            term = term.Substring(1, term.Length - 1);
            originalTerm = string.Copy(term);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!term.StartsWith("\"")) {
                // Escape special characters
                term = LuceneReservedCharacterPattern.Replace(term, @"\$0"); 
                // Then modify the term to improve phrase match:
                //      lyme disease OR "lyme disease"^2
                term = string.Concat("(", term, ") OR \"", term, "\"^2");
            }

            if (collections != null && !collections.Any(c => c.Equals("all", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) {
                // check for multiple collections collections: (all OR this OR that OR him OR her) etc
                term = string.Concat("(", term, ") AND collections:(", string.Join(" OR ", collections), ")");
            }
        }
```